# Webforms/MVC hybrid aspx error page being rendered through Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2, webforms-view-engine

We have a legacy webforms site that we have "successfully" integrated MVC and Web.Api into. If there are no server errors then all is good, pages render as expected. However if an MVC page gets a server error then it prints garbage.

> �����������������

I believe what is happening is that on an error it is attempting to push an aspx server error page through the Razor view engine. Has anyone seen this, and possibly know how to fix it to show the actual lemon meringue server error page?

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/GeneralErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/GeneralErrorPage.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPages/GeneralErrorPage.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: View engines are mutually exclusive, assuming the MVC pipeline is being invoked at all, so I don't believe a rendered WebForm is being put through Razor (or vice-versa). It looks more like the encoding's getting messed-up. What are the raw bytes of the response?

Comment: Whats your web config customErrors look like? Post your error hander page

Comment: @Dai The raw bytes as seen in Chrome DevTools looks the same as what I posted above with some other block random characters if I go into preview it looks as though they are a bunch of small fractions. 'ï¿½ï¿½Ys7ï¿½ï¿½3ï¿½*7ï¿½ï¿½),,ï¿½fÎ±qM'Nï¿'